# Thread Not Working

Tags: java, android, multithreading

The Thread t doesnt seem to work
I have tried to sysout and check in logcat, 
I have tried to change the textview

```
package com.android.wakey;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class finallytime extends Activity implements Runnable{

    boolean n = true;
    TextView tv;
    Thread t;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
        System.out.println("=======>>>>>> DONE");

        t = new Thread();

        t.start();

}
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        n=false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        n=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("====================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n==============================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + n);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(n){

        tv.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
        tv.setText("THis must work");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
        tv.setText((sdf.format(cal.getTime())).toString());

        try {
            t.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
    }}
```

This is a small code for android that i built but the thread doesnt seem to work
the text view doesn't change and still displays the default text.

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are actually 2 problems here, one is you never call the runnable for the thread

```
t = new Thread(this);
t.start();
```

the next is you are trying to update a UI element in a separate thread which you cannot do. so in the thread you need to us the `runOnUiThread()` method to update the textview

Comment: is there another way to update ui without using the given method and why do we do Thread(this).

Comment: @Mayank bcoz your class implements runnable and you must pass runnable object to the thread. You can use a handler instead of a thread

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
t = new Thread(this); // missing this
```

You are updating ui from a thread.

```
tv.setText("THis must work");
```

You should update ui from the ui thread. Use `runOnUiThread`

Declare `cal` and `sdf` as class members.

```
Calendar cal;
SimpleDateFormat sdf;
```

Then

```
@Override
public void run() {

    while(n){
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.getTime();
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tv.setText((sdf.format(cal.getTime())).toString());
        }
    });
    try {
        t.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```